# sorting documents in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, sorting

Let's say I have four documents in my collection:

```
{u'a': {u'time': 3}}
{u'a': {u'time': 5}}
{u'b': {u'time': 4}}
{u'b': {u'time': 2}}
```

Is it possible to sort them by the  field 'time' which is common in both 'a' and 'b' documents?

Thank you

Comment: Thank you all for your comments and suggestions. "The performance will be very poor for very large data sets." is clearly a show-stopper.  I might as well sort the documents in the application. As far the data itself, I didn't post the real data, because for one thing those are fairly complex documents. I just create this simple example that goes to the heart of the problem.

Comment: "sort the documents in the application"--I think I have suggested two options including this one. would you like to consider this to be your solution? On the other hand, if you can handle the data set at the client, the performance of the aggregation approach may not that bad. It would be interesting to know which method best fits you at the end.

Answer (score 0):

You can use use **[aggregation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/aggregation-zip-code-data-set/)** and the following code has been **tested**.

```
 db.test.aggregate({
      $project: {
          time: {
              "$cond": [{
                  "$gt": ["$a.time", null]
              }, "$a.time", "$b.time"]
          }
      }
  }, {
      $sort: {
          time: -1
      }
  });
```

Or if you also want the original fields returned back: [gist](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/83d701a83765de51b03c)

Alternatively you can sort once you get the result back, using a customized compare function ( **not tested**,for illustration purpose only)

```
db.eval(function() { 
  return  db.mycollection.find().toArray().sort( function(doc1, doc2) { 
       var time1 = doc1.a? doc1.a.time:doc1.b.time,
           time2 = doc2.a?doc2.a.time:doc2.b.time;
       return time1 -time2;
     })
});
```

Comment: Which would not sort the documents that are of the form `{ b : { time : 2 }}`

Answer (score 0):

No, you should put your data into a common format so you can sort it on a common field. It can still be nested if you want but it would need to have the same path.

Comment: the problem is that I can't put "my data" in a common format, because it's not my data, it's whatever is given to me.

Comment: "the same path" reminded me of the question I saw raised several years ago, whether mongodb would have XPath-like querying. I wonder whatever happened to that idea.

Comment: So ... you can create an index (which you would need for an efficient query on the time value) but you can't change the data in the database?!?? Why is that? What permissions do you have on the database? and what control do you have over other code in the system?

Answer (score 0):

You can, using the `aggregation framework`.

- The trick here is to `$project` a common field to all the documents so that the `$sort` stage can use the value in that field to `sort` the documents.
- The [***$ifNull***](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/ifNull/) operator can be used to check if `a.time` exists, it
  does, then the record will be sorted by that value else, by `b.time`.

code:

```
db.t.aggregate([
{$project:{"a":1,"b":1,
           "sortBy":{$ifNull:["$a.time","$b.time"]}}},
{$sort:{"sortBy":-1}},
{$project:{"a":1,"b":1}}
])
```

`consequences` of this approach:

- The `aggregation pipeline` **won't** be covered by any of the `index` you
  create.
- The performance will be very poor for very large data sets.

What you could ideally do is to ask the source system that is sending you the data to standardize its format, something like:

```
{"a":1,"time":5}
{"b":1,"time":4}
```

That way your query can make use of the `index` if you create one on the `time` field.

```
db.t.ensureIndex({"time":-1});
```

code:

```
db.t.find({}).sort({"time":-1});
```